# Creating multiple custom versions of the same android app

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I'm trying to create multiple versions of my app for different clients, and have done these steps:

-Duplicate all the folders with a simple copy and paste in the finder,

-Open the project i have just created,

-Changed the package name in the AndroidManifest.xml,

-Refactor all the classes and files that where failing (with the refactor option),

-Clear project and run.

I have been able to instal the 2 apps in the device, but every time I try to run any app the os shows me this:

[image]

As you can see I have the 2 app installed and running:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And every time i press a button ask me again:

[image]

This is the first AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="epinom.jm.smarthotel"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission android:name="epinom.jm.smarthotel.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature">

    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="epinom.jm.smarthotel.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                  android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyBjg8TtFgJTMuLFyiGlScVuEDNPjJnLxyM"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".vcMainScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="vcMainScreen" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the second AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <permission android:name="goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature">

    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="goSmart.guestperience.MoncloaDeSanLazaro.maps.googlev2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                  android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
               android:value="AIzaSyDNqe1PO7pvZLtba_Vu3m5BvmOdJtqhU0M"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity
            android:name=".vcMainScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="standard" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="vcMainScreen" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm starting with Android development so please tell me what I'm doing wrong, is there something that I'm missing to configure.

I'm using Eclipse on a Mac.

**TO ANWSER THE QUESTION OF @David**, this is the code i use to call every new screen:

```
String IntentName = Util.getController(buttons
        .getJSONObject(arg2)
        .getString("ViewController"));

Intent intento = new Intent(IntentName);

intento.putExtra(
        "jsonConfig",
        buttons.getJSONObject(arg2).getString(
                "JsonConfigFile"));
intento.putExtra("title", buttons.getJSONObject(arg2)
        .getString("Label"));
intento.putExtra("icon", buttons.getJSONObject(arg2)
        .getString("ImageIconTitle"));

startActivity(intento);
```

Comment: How do you handle the click on buttons to open an Activity?

On a sidenote, stop using Eclipse, use Android Studio and Gradle, study how "flavours" work, you will have a lot of this work done for you.

Comment: Hi, you are facing issues because of the intent filters, the system tries to check which all application can handle the type of intent you are requesting and then returns the application that can handle it. I would suggest using explicit intent or change the intent filter to some thing more specific to app.

Comment: @NimishChoudhary Sorry I'm super new with Android dev,I think that I don't fully understand what you are trying to tell me, so every time i start a new Activity the call is send to all the sister to see who can respond?? if this is true is there a way to resolve that??

Comment: @MarcoAntonioUzcateguiPescoz your code String IntentName = Util.getController(buttons
        .getJSONObject(arg2)
        .getString("ViewController"));

returns the same intent name for both the application, so try to make that different for each application.

Comment: @NimishChoudharyI have just done that, you gave me the clue with your previous comment, thanks my friend, i will add the answer to my specific code in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of Nimish Choudhary and more Google the answer to my problem was that I have to make unique all Activity names for to the 2 Apps.

So in the AndroidManifest.xml I have change all the names of all the Activities, i.e.:

```
     <activity
        android:name="app1.vcMainScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="standard" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="app1.vcMainScreen" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And I change the return of the switch when I was calling the function:

```
    Util.getController(buttons
            .getJSONObject(arg2)
            .getString("ViewController")
```

Now the return is:

```
    switch (Integer.parseInt(num)) {
    case 0:
        return "app1.vcMainScreen";
    default:
        return null;
    }
```

I hope this help someone one day.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 activities with the same name.... in differents App´s.

Change the name of 1 activity.